# VB.net Search Database using textbox

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a textbox in which a user can enter a hotel name and then clicks the Search button. A list of hotels with given name should be displayed upon doing so. Whenever I enter a hotel name and click the button, nothing gets displayed. Below is my code, thank you for any advice:

```
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim RegDataConn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source=" & Server.MapPath("App_Data/1202389.mdb"))

    Dim SearchHotel As String = TBSearch.Text

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT Hotel.Hotel_Name, Hotel.Hotel_Location FROM Hotel WHERE Hotel_Name Like '%" & SearchHotel & "%' ", RegDataConn)
    RegDataConn.Open()
    Dim myDA As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim myDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()
    myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "Table")
    GridView1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("Table").DefaultView



End Sub
```

Comment: I provided an answer and it was upvoted once but subsequently deleted by a moderator, although I'm not sure why.  It suggested that you call DataBind after setting the DataSource.  Did you try that?  Did it work?

Answer (score -2):

try to add plus sign(+) in you query
and add single quote after percent sign(%).

```
 WHERE Hotel_Name Like '%'+" & SearchHotel & "+'%'
```

Comment: That would produce a syntax error.  The query is fine as it is.